# How can I map two models from different data sources?

Tags: java, android, mapping, retrofit, android-room

I'm facing an issue in a project I'm currently developing.

I've been following package by feature structure for grouping my classes, and this is basically the structure I have:

```
 - data 
 - local 
  - model 
   - LocalModel.java
 - remote 
  - model
   - RemoteModel.java  
 - ui 
  - features
```

Both models contains exactly the same attributes,
i.e.:

**RemoteModel.java**

```
public class RemoteModel implements Parcelable {
   private String name; //has getter and setter
   ...
}
```

**LocalModel.java**

```
public class LocalModel implements Parcelable {
   private String name; //has getter and setter
   ...
}
```

Under the features package, I have an Activity for showing up the details of the models. The thing is, that the Activity can be started holding either a RemoteModel or a LocalModel object. But, as part of the attributes of that Activity it just has an RemoteModel attr, as follow:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompartActivity {
   ...
   private TextView mName;
   private RemoteModel mRemoteModel;
   ...

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      mRemoteModel = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_RESULT_TITLE);
      ...
      mName.setText(mRemoteModel.getName());
   }
}
```

That way it works fine until I run the app, and tap on view details button then the following beatiful error appears:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.carlosparra.myApp.data.local.model.LocalModel cannot be cast to com.carlosparra.moviestvtracker.moviesandtvshowstracker.data.remote.model.RemoteModel
```

I know what the error means, so that's why I'm wondering how can I map those two classes from different data sources in an shared object that I can pass it to the details Activity.

Comment: Do those classes have more methods than `Parcelable`?

Comment: @jhamon nope, just the ones that comes with the `Parcelable` implementation and their getters and setters

Comment: Have the getters/setters in `Parcelable`and set `mRemoteModel` as `Parcelable`instead of `RemoteModel`

Comment: Hmm, didn't follow you on "Have the getters/setters in `Parcelable`". Could you please provide me with a short example? Thanks in advanced

Comment: @Carlos Please try to create common model for both the features no need to create separate model.

Comment: `interface Parcelable { String getName(); }`

Comment: Cool, I had that in mind through an adapter. Thanks @jhamon

Answer (score 0):

You can define the necessary getters and setters in the interface `Parcelable`:

```
public interface Parcelable {

    String getName();

}
```

Then, instead of getting a `RemoteModel`in the activity, you get a `Parcelable` object:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompartActivity {
   ...
   private TextView mName;
   private Parcelable mParcelable;
   ...

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      mParcelable = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_RESULT_TITLE);
      ...
      mName.setText(mParcelable.getName());
   }
}
```